# Obtaining list of objects from client side in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm new to asp.net core. I've been reading and I know now how to submit data on a form as an object to the code behind, through post methods. That's fine. But how about sending a list of objects? What I would need to do would be (in this example it would be for an hotel management room types and rate types) something like a grid where I have a list of room types, where each one has a list of rate types. How can I do this? as I've done it, I can pass through the name of the room type (only as one object, though) but not any rates.

I have it like this (models):

```
public class RateType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

public class RoomType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<RateType> Rates { get; set; } = new List<RateType>();
    }
```

In the HomeController:

```
public IActionResult RoomConfig()
        {
            return View(room);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult SaveRoomConfig()
        {

            return View("RoomConfig");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult SaveRoomConfig(RoomType room)
        {

            return View("RoomConfig");
        }
```

And in the view:

```
@model RoomType
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RoomConfig";
}

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>

<form class="p-a-1" asp-action="SaveRoomConfig" method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Rates)
    {
        <label asp-for="Name">@item.Name </label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Name" />
        <input asp-for="@item.IsActive" type="checkbox" />

    }
    <button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

So, I send an initial object with some pre-defined values just for testing and they are shown on the page. But then, when I click "send" I can only send the first object (makes sense, since I only have an object parameter, so it will send only the first one. Still, I tried putting a list of RoomType's to see what it did but it shows count as zero. So, how can I do it? Pass a list of objects with another list of objects (nested). Is this possible? It doesn't make sense to make to only have the possibility to pass one and only single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized why it wasn't working. I was doing everything right, except for the fact that I was binding items to an empty list which, by definition, didn't have any items. So, instead of a 'foreach', I wrote a 'for' statement, in order to get to the index. That way, I binded the object to the position on the list, instead of a non-existing object. Like this:

```
@model RoomType
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RoomConfig";
}


<form class="p-a-1" asp-action="SaveRoomConfig" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    @for (int i=0;i< Model.Rates.Count;i++)
    {
        <div class=" form-control">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Rates[i].Name">@Model.Rates[i].Name </label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Rates[i].Name" />
            <input asp-for="@Model.Rates[i].IsActive" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

Of course, if anyone has a better way to do this I'm all ears. :)